# Image Grid-Attribute in XAML-C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a XAML code like this:

```
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.501,0.481">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/bg.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="670" Margin="50,40,0,0" Width="670" Background="#FFFFDF1A">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="bimage0" x:Uid="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="83.75" Width="83.75" Source="Assets/Chessman/bPawn.png" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="6"/>
        <Image x:Name="bimage1" x:Uid="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="83.75" Width="83.75" Source="Assets/Chessman/bPawn.png" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="6"/>
```

I want to get x:Uid and Grid.Row & Grid.Column Attribute for each Image Tag in C# part.

how can i do that?

is there anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Call the static `Grid` methods for row and column, and grab the `Uid` property from the image object itself.

```
int row = Grid.GetRow(bimage0);
int col = Grid.GetColumn(bimage0);
string uid = bimage0.Uid;
```

Comment: thanks so much, row and column trick works well.
but about the bimage0.Uid, i tryed it before but it said:
'Image' does not contain a definition for 'Uid' and no extension method 'Uid' accepting a first argument of type 'Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
any suggestion?

Comment: @MehrdadKamali, I just tried it here and it worked fine. You could try cleaning and rebuilding your solution. `Image` inherits from `UIElement`, which is what has the `Uid` property, so there should be no issue unless you're not using the correct `Image` control.

Comment: actually...it's work fine in WPF application... but i'm trying to build an universal app and the .Uid property doesn't exist in C# part even. Why?

Comment: @MehrdadKamali, because UWP is not the same as WPF. I'm not sure how you access it in that case. You may wish to check out this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034961/Using-resw-files-with-UWP-Compiled-Bindings